# Add Dates as labels to ggplot facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
  Date K Row Col Downward_solar_radiation Solar_radiation_calc
1 2014-01-02 1   1   1                        0                    0
2 2014-01-02 2   1   1                        0                    0
3 2014-01-02 3   1   1                        0                    0
4 2014-01-02 4   1   1                        0                    0
5 2014-01-02 5   1   1                        0                    0
6 2014-01-02 6   1   1                        0                    0
```

The data frame contains data for 30 different dates.
I am producing plots, one for each date, arranged in a grid using the following code snippet:

```
 df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=K)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=Downward_solar_radiation), color="red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y=Solar_radiation_calc), color="blue")+
    facet_grid(Col~Row)
```

The plot produced is:

[image]

I want to add a text to each plot depicting the corresponding date and get rid of labels 1-6.

Comment: why not use facet_grid(Date~Row)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `facet_wrap(~ Date, nrow=5)` instead of the `facet_grid`. This way, you don't need the manual col and row labels and ggplot will automatically label each facet with its corresponding date. [Documentation & examples](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html)